# CDI @Inject Named bean em outro Named bean

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2, cdi

Estou utilizando jsf 2.2. Tenho 2 @Named beans em @ViewScoped

```java
     @Named(value = "menuMB")
     @ViewScoped
     public class MenuMB implements Serializable{

     }
```

---

```java
     @Named(value = "produtoGeralMB")
     @ViewScoped
     public class ProdutoGeralMB  implements Serializable{
       @Inject
       private MenuMB menuMB;
     }
```

Dentro do `produtoGeralMB` tenho um método que altera uma propriedade do `menuMB`, porém na página jsf se eu uso em um inputText `#{menuMB.minhaPropriedade}`, apos o ajax não há alteração, se uso `#{produtoMB.menuMB.minhaPropriedade}` dá certo.

Percebi que o CDI trabalha com proxy para o objeto injetado. Existe alguma coisa para que na pagina eu use `#{menuMB.minhaPropriedade}` e não `#{produtoMB.menuMB.minhaPropriedade}`? Por que isso acontece se há apenas uma única instancia de `menuMB` em memória?

Answer (score 2):

Use a anotação [`javax.faces.view.ViewScoped`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/view/ViewScoped.html) do JSF 2.2 ao invés da tradicional [`javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/bean/ViewScoped.html) do CDI e tudo funcionará corretamente.

Na verdade, é recomendável descontinuar o uso de todas as anotações do pacote `javax.faces.bean` (que era o padrão no JSF 2.0):

DA [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/view/ViewScoped.html):

> The annotations in this package may be deprecated in a future version of this specification because they duplicate functionality provided by other specifications included in JavaEE. When possible, the corresponding annotations from the appropriate Java EE specification should be used in preference to these annotations. In this case, the corresponding annotation is `javax.faces.view.ViewScoped`. The functionality of this corresponding annotation is identical to this one, but it is implemented as a CDI custom scope.

Que pode ser livremente traduzido para:

> As anotações nesse pacote podem ser depreciadas em uma versão futura dessa especificação porque elas duplicam funcionalidades providas por outras especificações incluídas no Java EE. Quando possível as anotações correspondentes da especificação Java EE devem ser utilizadas em preferência a essas anotações. Nesse caso, a anotação correspondente é `javax.faces.view.ViewScoped`. A funcionalidade dessa anotação correspondente é idêntica a essa, mas ela é implementada como um escopo customizado do CDI.

**Referência:** [JSF SPEC PUBLIC 1087](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES_SPEC_PUBLIC-1087)

Comment: Já estou usando javax.faces.view.ViewScoped

Comment: Talvez seja um bug na sua implementação (ou na combinação de componentes do ambiente). Tente obter o bean diretamente do contexto para ver se o mesmo está devidamente populado: `context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{menuMB}", MenuMB.class);`. Seu problema também parece muito com [esse aqui](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12513374/injected-session-scoped-bean-in-view-scoped-bean-duplicating) (em inglês). Talvez valha a pena tentar mudar o `javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD` para `server`

Comment: Finalmente. Se nada mais der certo, mande bala no [MyFaces](http://myfaces.apache.org/core22/) + [CODI](http://myfaces.apache.org/extensions/cdi/) (não sei qual a sua implementação mas eu já bati em bugs semelhantes no Mojarra e estou bastante satisfeito com o MyFaces).

Comment: javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD já estava como server. Tentei também o parcial_state_saving false mas não foi possível usar com Richfaces4. Quando eu obtenho pelo contexto menuMB está populdo. Acredito também que seja algo da implementação, estou tentando utilizar a ultima versão de tudo, richfaces4 + glassfish4 + jsf 2.2.5. Vou fazer um teste com CODI. Obrigado pela atenção!

Comment: O GlassFish 4 vem com Mojarra, troque pelo MyFaces + CODI que é certeza que vai (estou com uma aplicação fazendo algo semelhante no Jetty). Pelo menos você tem o work-around agora (recupere diretamente do contexto).